# Elasticsearch NodeJS client shows inaccessible node as alive

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, connection

I have a simple function in NodeJS which creates an Elasticsearch client with a cluster of nodes and returns one of the node URLs that is active:

```
// Elastic cluster nodes
const ELASTIC_CLUSTER_NODES = [
    'http://node1.domain.com:9200',
    'http://node2.domain.com:9200',
    'http://node3.domain.com:9200',
];

async function getElasticsearchUrl() {
    const { Client } = require('@elastic/elasticsearch');
    const client = new Client({
        nodes: ELASTIC_CLUSTER_NODES,
        sniffOnStart: true,
        sniffOnConnectionFail: true,
        snifferTimeout: 60,
        auth: {
            username: 'username',
            password: 'password'
        }
    });

    // Return the first alive connection URL.
    return (await client).connectionPool.connections.find((connection) => {
        return connection.status === "alive";
    }).url;
}
exports.getElasticsearchUrl = getElasticsearchUrl;
```

`node1` is currently down. The expectation is that the client will sniff the hosts and return only 2 nodes that are alive - `node2` and `node3`.

However, the client returns all 3 nodes as alive:

```
"connections": [
            {
                "url": "http://node1.domain.com:9200/",
                "id": "http://node1.domain.com:9200/",
                "headers": {},
                "deadCount": 0,
                "resurrectTimeout": 0,
                "_openRequests": 1,
                "status": "alive",
                "roles": {
                    "master": true,
                    "data": true,
                    "ingest": true,
                    "ml": false
                }
            },
            {
                "url": "http://node2.domain.com:9200/",
                "id": "http://node2.domain.com:9200/",
                "headers": {},
                "deadCount": 0,
                "resurrectTimeout": 0,
                "_openRequests": 0,
                "status": "alive",
                "roles": {
                    "master": true,
                    "data": true,
                    "ingest": true,
                    "ml": false
                }
            },
            {
                "url": "http://node3.domain.com:9200/",
                "id": "http://node3.domain.com:9200/",
                "headers": {},
                "deadCount": 0,
                "resurrectTimeout": 0,
                "_openRequests": 0,
                "status": "alive",
                "roles": {
                    "master": true,
                    "data": true,
                    "ingest": true,
                    "ml": false
                }
            }
        ],
```

This causes the application to use `node1`'s URL which is inaccessible, resulting in the application breaking. I cross-checked with the `_nodes` API which accurately returns 2 nodes as being alive:

```
{
  "_nodes": {
    "total": 2,
    "successful": 2,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "cluster_name": "my-cluster",
  "nodes": {
    "OcQeD7-cgRV_rMEkw21oAm": {
      "name": "node3",
      "transport_address": "xx.xxx.xx.100:9300",
      "host": "xx.xxx.xx.100",
      "ip": "xx.xxx.xx.100",
      "version": "7.13.0",
      "build_flavor": "default",
      "build_type": "rpm",
      "build_hash": "528ef91cc5cba6855f0a35386d966390ec1b20c5",
      "roles": [
        "data",
        "data_cold",
        "data_content",
        "data_frozen",
        "data_hot",
        "data_warm",
        "ingest",
        "master",
        "ml",
        "remote_cluster_client",
        "transform"
      ],
      "attributes": {
        "ml.machine_memory": "8201256960",
        "ml.max_open_jobs": "512",
        "xpack.installed": "true",
        "ml.max_jvm_size": "4102029312",
        "transform.node": "true"
      },
      "http": {
        "bound_address": [
          "xx.xxx.xx.100:9200"
        ],
        "publish_address": "xx.xxx.xx.100:9200",
        "max_content_length_in_bytes": 104857600
      }
    },
    "N--DVxaQzbvDQqkUju9-Uu": {
      "name": "node2",
      "transport_address": "xx.xxx.xx.99:9300",
      "host": "xx.xxx.xx.99",
      "ip": "xx.xxx.xx.99",
      "version": "7.13.0",
      "build_flavor": "default",
      "build_type": "rpm",
      "build_hash": "3169552cdbce523538ec0f1fc98a6a665cb98500",
      "roles": [
        "data",
        "data_cold",
        "data_content",
        "data_frozen",
        "data_hot",
        "data_warm",
        "ingest",
        "master",
        "ml",
        "remote_cluster_client",
        "transform"
      ],
      "attributes": {
        "ml.machine_memory": "8201273344",
        "xpack.installed": "true",
        "transform.node": "true",
        "ml.max_open_jobs": "512",
        "ml.max_jvm_size": "4102029312"
      },
      "http": {
        "bound_address": [
          "xx.xxx.xx.99:9200"
        ],
        "publish_address": "xx.xxx.xx.99:9200",
        "max_content_length_in_bytes": 104857600
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there anything wrong with the code or the logic to fetch the first available working Elasticsearch node URL? Any information on this would be really helpful.

*Note: All sensitive info has been obfuscated.*

Comment: The question is why don't you let the client handle its connection pool? You should not have to worry about that, the client is smart enough to route the request to nodes that are available.

Comment: @Val The application was initially written against a single node in the cluster. Unarguably, a poor practice. It would take a lot of refactoring to change code expecting a URL to now use the client.

Comment: So if I get this right, you're not using the client at all and the only reason to build that client is to get an URL out of it that you can shove inside another client??

Comment: @Val The client is in use for all new functionality. For cases where REST calls were directly being made to the node, the function returns a URL.

Comment: How about setting up a real load balancer so you don't have to worry about this anymore? Keeping this kind of logic is calling for troubles

Comment: @Val I do plan on refactoring everything to use the client directly at this point. However, I'm still curious as to why this is happening. Bug in the NodeJS Elasticsearch library?

Comment: There can be many reasons, but this article would probably provide more insights: https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-sniffing-best-practices-what-when-why-how